# Как сделать заключительный этап регистрации брони через смс с кодом в Telegram боте

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Заказчик просит сделать бота в котором клиент должен подтвердить свою бронь в telegram боте с помощью смс с кодом который ему придет на телефон , как мне это реализовать в Python aiogram? Да я знаю что в aiogram есть функция отправки своего номера но я не знаю как ее использовать.

Comment: На телефон откуда приходит смс?

Comment: честно не знаю, поэтому и написал сюда, я пытался найти бб python с работой смс кодами но ничего не нашел

Comment: Если я правильно понял то получается как - то так - Клиенту приходит СМС - код, ему требуется зайти в бота и подтвердить этот код. Если я все правильно понял, то вам требуется источник который генерирует это коды. Сопоставлять и сравнивать их в боте, и подтверждать бронь. вроде изи

Comment: мне посоветовали кое где просто проверять user.id контакта который отправили и user.id самого пользователя

Comment: да именно так, я не знаю как генерировать коды и сравнивать их в телеграм боте для того что бы подтвердить бронь\услугу

Comment: Стоп, отправкой этого кода клиенту вы заниматься из выше сказанного как я понял не должны. Во-первых(я не сильно шарю) у компании должно быть что-то типа телефонии(зарегистрированного номера) или они должны пользоваться подобным сервисом, который отправляет этот код. Ваше дело малое получить этот код(точнее вашему боту) и далее тупо сравнить. Если это какой-то сервис, возможно у него есть API

Comment: опять же если вы не напутали ничего, мне объясняя. Если это тупо все делается в телеграмме, то конечно расклад другой

Comment: Спасибо за совет, спрошу у заказчика есть ли у них сервис с данной задачей или зарегистрированный номер, можете подсказать как это правильно называется (я про сервис с смс кодами или зарегистрированный номер для смс кодов)

Comment: да весь процесс брони делается в телеграме, сайт не используется

Comment: Вы не поняли, СМС с кодом будет высылаться на номер телефона??? Или вашему боссу требуется это провернуть тупо через телегу?  вот -> https://smsc.ru/call-code/

Comment: Да, номер нужен для того чтоб на него просто пришел код а сам код нужен для подтверждения брони\услуги в телеге

Comment: берете любой сервис для рассылки смс и все. Для генерации кода и его хранения пишите отдельный сервис. Хранить в базе user.id - код. Потом его сравниваете с введенным

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, в целом - все так. https://www.smsc.ru/reg/